# iterate trough cells of a unique value in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported a csv to a dataframe, each unique value of a name needs to have 4 types of files `(Color, 012, 026, 028)`.
This is an example of my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['color', '012', '026', '028', 'color', '012', '028'], 'name': ['p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p1','p2', 'p2', 'p2']})
```

I am trying make a new list with the missing types of files, so for example, for my df I would like the output to be:

```
({'type': ['026'], 'name': ['p2']})
```

I tried using `groupby('name')` but didn't get to far.

It seems like something very basic but I cant get my grip around it, I am not sure if to use a for loop or if there is an iteration method or a List Comprehensions I can use here.

Thanks!

I managed to locate those that don't have 4 rows but I was not able to

Answer (score 0):

**To get output in the form of dict**

```
req_type={'color', '012', '026', '028'}
df.groupby('name')['type'].apply(lambda x: list(req_type-set(x))[0] if len(req_type-set(x))==1 else list(req_type-set(x))
                         if set(x) != req_type else np.nan).to_frame().dropna().reset_index().to_dict('list')
```

**Output**

```
{'name': ['p2'], 'type': ['026']}
```

**If the output is required as df**

**Code**

```
req_type={'color', '012', '026', '028'}
df.groupby('name')['type'].apply(lambda x: list(req_type-set(x))[0] if len(req_type-set(x))==1 else list(req_type-set(x))
                     if set(x) != req_type else np.nan).to_frame().dropna().reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    name    type
0   p2      026
```

**Explanation**
We are having a `set named req_type` to have all required values of `type column`.
Then we are `grouping df by name` and checking if each group of name is having `all values from req_type set`, if not then we are fetching those values.
Inner if conditions is placed if there are more than one type missing for a name group then the output will be have type as a list with more than one value like `{'name': ['p2'], 'type': [['028', '026']]}`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, I used the df option and it indeed gave me what I wanted

Comment: Nw, all the best. You have an option to accept the answer by clicking tick.